# Script to add ICC color profile to images after PHP GD strips it?

Tags: php, colors, gd, color-profile, color-management

I use an online shopping cart to sell my photography. The software dynamically resizes and watermarks images using GD library and when it does, it strips all metadata, including the ICC color profile necessary to make the images display properly in color managed browsers. I am talking sRGB here.

Is there any way to make a script that could run after the GD transformations that could add an ICC profile to the images automatically? At this point, I don't think ImageMagick is an option.

Thanks!